# Aligning Text Directly Under Text Input

Tags: html, css

this is my HTML and CSS:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="navrow">
    <img style="float: left;" src="questerslogoresized.png" />
    <ul>
        <li>Register</li>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        <li>About</li>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        <li>Reviews</li>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        <form id='login' action='<?php echo $fgmembersite->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method='post'>
            <div style="position: absolute; right: 120px;">
                <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1' />
                <label for="username">Your username goes here</label>
                <input type='text' name='username' class="formlogin" placeholder='Username' id='username' value='<?php echo $fgmembersite->SafeDisplay(' username ') ?>' maxlength="20" />
                <span id='login_username_errorloc' class='error'></span>
                <input type='password' class="formlogin" placeholder="Password" name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />
                <span id='login_password_errorloc' class='error'></span>
            </div>
            <input type='submit' style='position: absolute; top: 18px; right: 45px;' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
            <!--<div class='short_explanation'><a href='reset-pwd-req.php'>Forgot Password?</a></div>-->
        </form>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#navrow {
    background: #ffc966;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 75px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px #000;
}
.formlogin {
    border-radius: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
    height: 24px;
    /*width: 200px;*/
    padding: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #0093cc;
    -webkit-transition: border-color 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: border-color 1s ease;
    -o-transition: border-color 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: border-color 1s ease;
    transition: border-color 1s ease;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 12.5em;
    position: relative;
    top: -2em;
}
```

I'm wondering how I can get the label for username (Your username goes here) located directly underneath the username input field.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks again Stack Overflow!

Comment: Do you want the text to be inside the textbox

Comment: The problem im having is that i do not understand the questionm If i could i would help but be more specific

Comment: I mean have the text underneath the textbox.

Comment: Please note that you can't put anything except list items in a list. So no `&nbsp` and no `<form>` Also, the `&nbsp`s should end in semicolons.

Comment: I recommend you to fix your HTML code first: remove strange `&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp`, move form from list to another place

Comment: I need them to increase the space between Register, About and Reviews.

Comment: You can increase these spaces by CSS

Comment: I think it's fine leaving them how it is. If it's not broke, don't fix it.

Comment: @JugglingBob Please don't do that. It IS broke. Sure, you may have found this dirty trick happens to work in the browser you are testing on, but I know browsers where this _doesn't_ work. So stick to correct HTML; it will have a much better chance of showing up the same in different browsers. In this case, CSS is the solution, but if you don't want to use CSS, put some `<br>`s in the `<li>`s. Not in between.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean something like [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sbyf9wka/).

The idea is to wrap the `input` and `label` with a `div`, `div.form-controls` in my example. Then, set the `input` and `label` to block elements and the label should come beneath the input.

I have also removed the `position` values from couple of elements. Tweak it as per your needs.

```css
#navrow {
  background: #ffc966;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 75px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px #000;
}
.formlogin {
  border-radius: 12px 12px 12px 12px;
  height: 24px;
  /*width: 200px;*/
  padding: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #0093cc;
  -webkit-transition: border-color 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: border-color 1s ease;
  -o-transition: border-color 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: border-color 1s ease;
  transition: border-color 1s ease;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 12.5em;
}
.form-controls {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="navrow">
  <img style="float: left;" src="questerslogoresized.png" />
  <ul>
    <li>Register</li>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
    <li>About</li>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
    <li>Reviews</li>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
    <form id='login' action='<?php echo $fgmembersite->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method='post'>
      <div>
        <div class="form-controls">
          <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1' />
          <input type='text' name='username' class="formlogin" placeholder='Username' id='username' value='' maxlength="20" />
          <label for="username">Your username goes here</label> <span id='login_username_errorloc' class='error'></span>

        </div>
        <div class="form-controls">
          <input type='password' class="formlogin" placeholder="Password" name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />
          <span id='login_password_errorloc' class='error'></span>

        </div>
        <p style="clear:both"></p>
      </div>
      <input type='submit' style='position: absolute; top: 18px; right: 45px;' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
      <!--<div class='short_explanation'><a href='reset-pwd-req.php'>Forgot Password?</a></div>--></div>
</form>
</ul>
```

### Alert! Good Practices -

- **DON'T** use `&nbsp;` for space issues. There's CSS for that.
- Shorthands! `border-radius: 12px 12px 12px 12px;` could just be `border-radius : 12px;`
- **DON'T** use inline styles. Again, there is CSS for that.

Comment: Great solution, one problem though - when I click submit, the text input moves left and the message appears in its place: http://prntscr.com/7cjezd

Comment: add `display:block` for the `span` containing the message or change it to a block element like `p` or a `div`